# How to import old SIM contacts to Galaxy Nexus?

Tags: backup, samsung-galaxy-nexus, sim-card

I would like to import the contacts from my old phone to GN. I read [this guide here](http://support.google.com/ics/nexus/bin/answer.py?answer=1688401&topic=1635774&ctx=topic), but there is no "Menu" in the *People* app. I'm running 4.0.2.

Please, does anyone know how to proceed? Why there is no "Menu" if the manual says there should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there has to be at least one other contact, then there are these "three dots".